# Discussion on RecyclerViews ability

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

To show a list of items I usually use a RecyclerView but I have a requirement that makes it easier for me to use a vertical LinearLayout. I don't want to loose the good resource management of the RecyclerView so I'm looking for a different solution and hope someone can help me.

I think of a layout with some views on top, then a list of items followed by some more views on the bottom. Or a layout that contains more than one RecyclerView. So you have some Views on the top, a list of items followed by some more views and another list of items etc.

My layout could look like this:

- View1
- View2
- RecyclerView
- View3
- RecyclerView
- View4

Usually a RecyclerView works like a scrollable frame in which you can scroll some content. It means that if you start scrolling, your whole screen gets stuck in a certain position and you are just scrolling in the RecyclerView until its end. Then you can continue scrolling the whole screen.

What I want is a RecyclerView that is fully inflated so you are always scrolling the whole screen instead of just the RecyclerView but not loosing the resource management of the RecyclerView.

Does anybody know of a solution of this?

Comment: the setup you described is certainly possible, if the height of each view (including both RecyclerView)  is very short.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation i use only one `RecycleView` implementing my own [getItemViewType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int))

Answer (score 1):

add below code to your custom adapter of recycler view

```
  @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_NORMAL) {
            View normalView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_normal_row, null);
            return new MyNormalViewHolder(normalView); // view holder for normal items
        } else if (viewType == ITEM_TYPE_HEADER) {
            View headerRow = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_header_row, null);
            return new MyHeaderViewHolder(headerRow); // view holder for header items
        }
    }
```

What i suggest is to use a single recyclerview with custom adapter and inflate each row of recyclerview with diff layout ie.... based on your condition

Answer (score 0):

The best answer will depend on what behaviour you want for the screen as a whole.

"What I want is a RecyclerView that is fully inflated so you are always scrolling the whole screen instead of just the RecyclerView but not loosing the resource management of the RecyclerView."

This requirement makes me think that the best option indeed is a single RecyclerView using different ViewHolder types like @Rissmon Suresh and @betorcs mentioned.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {



        class HeaderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            ...
        }


        class NormalViewHolder1 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            ...
        }



        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            // use position to decide what kind of View you want
            // can be fixed or you can access the data to check dinamically

            if(position == 0)
               return 0;
            else
               return 1;
        }


        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

             switch (viewType) {
                 case 0: return new HeaderViewHolder(...);
                 case 1: return new NormalViewHolder1(...);
                 //...
             }
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps =)

Comment: have you been able to solve your problem? let me know if this helped =)